# CSS to Remove Top Grey line of a HTML page

Tags: css, html

I am trying to develop a webpage where I would like to remove the space on the top of my page so that the content will start just when the page starts, without any gap. Just like below.

[image]

But when I try to do the same for my page, I see a grey line on the top of my page and I am not able to remove that.

[image]

As you can see my red banner has a gap on top of it, unlike the previous picture. The CSS I am using is:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11.5px;
    color:#4C464D;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    vertical-align: baseline; 
}
```

--To my surprise, there is absolutely nothing in the page, but I still see the line.

The code I kept very basic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: We need a [mcve], not a single CSS rule

Comment: That's looks like the bottom of the browser toolbar...

Comment: We would also need the code for _at least_ the red bar you are using, as the problem is probably not related to your `body`. It looks like the red bar has some sort of `border` applied to it.

Comment: That's not a grey line, it's the shadow from the IE toolbar.  You've not really posted enough to go on, but it's probably because you've not used a CSS reset, and so something like the `html` tag has some padding or margin.  Use Chrome's Inspect Element to take a look, or post more information, such as your complete HTML and CSS, if that doesn't help.

Comment: I've seen your edit, and like I said: it's the shadow from the IE toolbar.  Use a CSS reset before all of your other CSS, that will almost definitely be the reason > https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a container? Maybe that could be the problem.

Example:

```html
 <body>
 <div class="container">
 Site goes here
 </div>
 </body>
```